# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left\lfloor\frac{5}{5^k}\right\rfloor$ giving wrong answer?

Tags: bugs, symbolic, summation

**Bug introduced in 7.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

When I try to evaluate the following:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\Bigg\lfloor\frac{5}{5^k}\Bigg\rfloor$$

using

```
Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, ∞}]
```

Mathematica provides an answer of $0$ when it clearly should be $1$. Using any finite limit for the summation, however, provides the correct answer. Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the code you are using to get your result?

Comment: I'm sure a similar question has come up, but I can't find it.  (Different summand, but finite vs. infinite sum give inconsistent results.)  Maybe someone will find it.

Comment: Interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690884/issue-with-sum-of-floors-in-mathematica

Comment: @Leucippus The standard way for sums: `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]`

Comment: @Kurt That does seem to be related... surprising that a computational bug hasn't been fixed even 2 major versions later.

Comment: It sure is weird. NSum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, \[Infinity]}] gets 1.

Comment: The sum `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, 10^a}]` gives up at `a=16` =)))

Comment: Fascinating. `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]` gives the expected `6`, while `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, a, Infinity}]` gives 0 for all larger `a` I've tested.

Comment: The reason why a finite limit gives a good result is that in that case Mathematica computes the result directly: calculate each term, sum them up.  Using a symbolic limit also results in `0`.  I don't have any insight into why it misses the `k == 1` case when doing it symbolically.  Tagging as bug.

Comment: It seems to work fine when the numerator is not equal to the denominator. 6/3^k works, for instance.

Comment: @Szabolcs, i.e. such finit limit `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, 10^20}]` gives `0`. But `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 0.99999999, Infinity}]` gives `1`.  Definitely bug

Comment: The code `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, 1000}]` gives the value of `1`.

Comment: Moreover, the following equivalent commands are evaluated incorrectly (version 9.0.1.0, OS X):  `Sum[Floor[5^-k], {k,0,Infinity}]`, and `Sum[Floor[1/5^k], {k,0,Infinity}]`.

Comment: Came here to point out what @garej said. And also noticed `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 0.999999999999999, Infinity}]` is `1`, but, add one more digit `Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 0.9999999999999999, Infinity}]` and we're at `0` again. Also, both have `Accuracy[]` of `15.9546`

Comment: NSum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, ∞}] is 1, though.

Comment: How odd; nobody has linked to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1088)...

Comment: sobbing ! Mathematica ver 10.4 comes out with the same wrong answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in the just released Mathematica 11.0.1.

```
Sum[Floor[5/5^k], {k, 1, Infinity}]

(* 1 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

This is certainly a bug, but one the user is warned about. The help section on "Possible Issues" provides a couple of examples where `Sum` gives "*an unexpected result*" (read: a wrong one). It's always related to using some discrete function that cannot be evaluated symbolically, like `PrimeQ` or `Plus@*IntegerDigits`, and ends up oversimplified at the attempt. I strongly believe your case is no different because [5/5^k] is zero in all points *inside* [1,+∞), so perhaps Mathematica simplifies the summand to zero when trying to perform its symbolic methods. The remedy advised by the official help is to "prevent symbolic evaluation" by specifying a `Method` (none of the official list works, which should be a hint) or by making the sum finite.

Comment: Good guess, and in fact it was my initial guess when I first saw this. But it turns out to be an actual bug insofar as there is explicit code to handle this type of problem, and it is going awry somewhere.